# How to draw a circular image in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Let's say I have a rectangular avatar image like the one below, how can I force it to be drawn as a circle in Jetpack Compose?

[image]

Answer (score 171):

There's a [clip](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/draw/package-summary#clip) modifier which can be applied to any composable as well as the [`Image`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary#image), just pass  a [`CircleShape`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/shape/package-summary?hl=en#circleshape) into it:

```kotlin
Image(
    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.sample_avatar),
    contentDescription = "avatar",
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,            // crop the image if it's not a square
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(64.dp)
        .clip(CircleShape)                       // clip to the circle shape
        .border(2.dp, Color.Gray, CircleShape)   // add a border (optional)
)
```

[image]

You can use any other shape to clip the image, for example `CircleShape` it's just [`RoundedCornerShape(percent = 50)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/shape/RoundedCornerShape). Let's try `RoundedCornerShape(percent = 10)`:

[image]

Comment: This works well until I use the padding modifier. Someone has an idea?

Comment: The same for `AsyncImage` (using `model` instead of `painter`).

Comment: @ErdalG. I needed a padding so instead used a Box with the clip as CircleShape and put the image inside it centered. It worked!

Answer (score 7):

For those who wonder how to make an image squared (or round) without explicitly setting its sizes, there is `Modifier.aspectRatio(1f)`

Answer (score 5):

Also, you may try a

> `implementation "com.github.skydoves:landscapist-glide:1.3.6"`

By using `Modifier.clip(CircleShape)`

```
GlideImage(
            modifier = Modifier
                    .width(50.dp)
                    .height(50.dp)
                    .clip(CircleShape)
                    .clickable(enabled = true, onClick = onClick),
            imageModel = "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/27887884?v=4",
                // Crop, Fit, Inside, FillHeight, FillWidth, None
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                // shows an image with a circular revealed animation.
            circularReveal = CircularReveal(duration = 250),
                // shows a placeholder ImageBitmap when loading.
            placeHolder = ImageBitmap.imageResource(R.drawable.avater),
                // shows an error ImageBitmap when the request failed.
            error = ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = R.drawable.avater)
            )
```

For more components visit [LandScapist](https://github.com/skydoves/landscapist)

Answer (score 4):

[image]We can achieve this using the ***background field*** in a **modifier**.

```
Image(
  painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_arrow_right),
  contentDescription = "",
  modifier = Modifier
             .padding(4.dp, 4.dp).background(colorResource(id = R.color.greenColor), CircleShape)
              .clip(CircleShape),
  colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(colorResource(id = R.color.white)),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

For circular image in jetpack compose:

```
Image(modifier = Modifier.clip(CircleShape), contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth)
```