# How to achieve this in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Ok so ive been wondering how to achieve this floating action button or just an imageView in compose.

In xml i was able to reproduce this by using a negative margin ( which isnt the way to go )

But this entire screen is done already by JetPack Compose and the root view is a Column.

I honestly have no idea not even how to google that thats why i got the image here as context. thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66014834/11292068 I think this what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

[image]

```
@Composable
fun TopAppBarScreen() {

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        TopAppBar(
            elevation = 5.dp,
            backgroundColor = Color(0XFFF05E32)
        ) {
            IconButton(onClick = {}) {
                Icon(Icons.Default.ArrowBack, contentDescription = "", tint = Color.White)
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
            Text(text = "Menu Prefil", color = Color.White)
        }
        FloatingActionButton(
            onClick = {},
            backgroundColor = Color(0XFF4c8acc),
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.TopEnd)
                .padding(end = 20.dp, top = 25.dp)
        ) {
            Icon(Icons.Default.ShoppingCart, contentDescription = "", tint = Color.White)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: wow thank you so much, thats definetely a way of doing it.